# Is there any down side to robbing black markets?

Tags: dishonored-2

I found out in mission 2 that I can rob the black market. It takes extra work up front, but after opening the door, are there any downsides to robbing the black market(s) instead of paying for items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the black market dealers will ask you to do things for you or have unique dialog. If you rob them, and the method by which you rob them spooks them into running away, you will potentially lose access to those quests or dialog if you haven't yet experienced it.

(Particularly since, I've noticed so far, many civilians stay in their "scared and running away" state basically forever and never return to their original behavior.)

It's also possible that opening the shutters & stealing from their shelves without scaring them off prevents them from selling you any more of whatever you stole, but I have not been able to test this yet.

Comment: So to follow up: If you have exhausted their quests, and you don't mind them running, there should be no down sides? Are quests contained within a single mission, or might they come up in future missions? (e.g. if mission is "complete" anyway, there is no further harm)

Answer (score 2):

On additional downside I've noticed: You steal all the gear in the case, but lose access to purchasing active blueprints, including new ones you might find later in the mission.

In my case I found a new blueprint, and had no way to purchase it. I would assume they would be purchasable at the next black market instead, but I haven't played that far yet.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Once you find a blueprint, you can visit any black market shop, in the same mission or a later one, and the upgrade will become available at every black market shop you encounter for the remainder of the playthrough.

Comment: There is at least one blueprint in the final level, and if you robbed that shop you'll never be able to use it.